# python two foorloops comprehension containing sum

Tags: python-3.x

is it possible to do this code using List comprehension

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(h)):
        res[i + j] = res[i + j] + x[i] * h[j]
```

Comment: Can you give a numeric example *which works* if we were to run it?

Comment: why would you? the very fact you have to ask how to do it means you shouldn't do it.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html can likely do this.

Comment: @hop: for one, this pair of loops does about twice as much assignments than a hypothetic one-pass algorithms would.

Comment: @9000: what does the choice of for-loop vs. list comprehension have to do with the choice of algorithm? if the algorithm is inefficient, fix it first, then /maybe/ worry about list comprehensions.

Comment: @hop: frankly, not even the algorithm; it's a typical "XY-problem". it should be upcasted from "how do I alter this code" to "how do I compute a convolution", _then_ good solutions are much easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
res = list(numpy.convolve(x, h))
```

It's the same thing, I checked this out

Testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
import numpy                                                                
from random import random, randint                                          

x = [random() for _ in range(randint(10, 20))]                              
h = [random() for _ in range(randint(10, 20))]                              

res1 = [0] * (len(x) + len(h) - 1)                                          
for i in range(len(x)):                                                     
    for j in range(len(h)):                                                 
        res1[i + j] = res1[i + j] + x[i] * h[j]                             

res2 = list(numpy.convolve(x, h))                                           

diff = sum(abs(r1 - r2) for (r1, r2) in zip(res1, res2))                    
print(diff)
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.py 
0.0
$ ./test.py 
0.0
$ ./test.py 
1.7763568394e-15
$ ./test.py 
2.22044604925e-15
$ ./test.py 
0.0
$ ./test.py 
6.99440505514e-15
$ ./test.py 
8.54871728961e-15
```

Comment: Thanks my point wasn't to do convolution , it was just to see if it's possible to do it using list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the ugliest list comprehension I've ever written, but this *does* work:

```
res = [sum(x[i] * h[k - i] for i in range(k+1) if 0 <= k-i < len(h) and 0 <= i < len(x)) for k in range(len(x) + len(h) - 1)]
```

Please, for the love of all that's good in this world, don't actually use that in your code.

Comment: Why would you even publish this?

Answer (score -1):

In short, no, if you want to reproduce the exact computation.

Your loop assigns many elements of `res` several times; e.g. `res[3]` will be assigned for `i` and `j` combinations 0 + 3, 1 + 2, 2 + 1, 3 + 0. Every time, the previous value will be used, so the order of computation is important.

Maybe it's possible to re-formulate your problem so that a list comprehension (possibly nested) could generate the values without re-assigning them, because it can't re-assign already generated elements.

Comment: since addition is commutative, order is not important in this case.

Comment: @hop: Even with commutative `+`, first we need to prove that any intermadiate results do not influence other results. (Should be pretty doable in this case.)